# How to use PAM to restrict HTTP access for some users?

Tags: networking, permissions, pam

I've read that PAM can be used to restrict HTTP access for some users, but I can't figure out how to do it in Ubuntu 12.04.

The `/etc/security/time.conf` man page contains this example:

```
All users except for root are denied access to console-login at all times:

    login ; tty* & !ttyp* ; !root ; !Al0000-2400
```

For this to work, `/etc/pam.d/login` needs to have a line

```
account    requisite  pam_time.so
```

This example works, and I tried to adapt it to limit HTTP access from the console. I added

```
http ; tty* & !ttyp* ; !root ; !Al0000-2400
```

to `/etc/security/time.conf`, and created `/etc/pam.d/http` with

```
account    requisite  pam_time.so
```

This doesn't work. I can still use `wget` as non-root from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't -- wget doesn't use PAM. A program must be explicitly designed to call PAM for it to have any affect. If you heard PAM could be used with HTTP, then it may have been a conversation about using PAM to authenticate a user trying to log in to a web site.